# How do I sort cart items?

Tags: cart, quote, sorting, magento-1.5

I am trying to sort the items based on the order they were added to the cart (oldest at the top, each item added under that). **Is there any logical method to the way cart items are sorted in Magento 1.5?** I can't seem to find a pattern!

I've been trying to sort using this on /app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml

```
$cartitems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->setQuote($this->getQuote())->addFieldToSelect('updated_at')->addOrder('updated_at', 'asc');

$items = array();
foreach ($cartitems as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
        $items[] = $item;
    }
}
```

And then looping though the items per usual...

```
<?php foreach($items as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I also need to sort cart items on a mini cart that drops down when you hover over a cart link in the header. It's working great except the ordering.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to sort, and just when I think I have it, all I need to do is change the qty of one of the items and they are all out of order again.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I have found a [couple things](http://daniel.gd/how-to-sort-items-in-magentos-cart-page/) [to try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140053/magento-how-to-display-items-in-cart-in-the-order-they-were-added) but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the data that the item was added to the cart you could try `created_at` on the table `sales_falt_quote_item`

```
$cartitems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->setQuote($this->getQuote())
    ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')->addOrder('created_at', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick way out:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php

```
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()**->setOrder('updated_at','desc');**
            $this->_items->setQuote($this);
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }
```

You can always create a local file so that the core files are not overwritten.

Comment: I have that in place (local file), but it seems if I change the qty of one of the items in the cart, they change ordering. 

Are there other options other than `updated_at`?